# What file format is appropriate for logging/configuration files?

Tags: c++, logging, configuration-files

I do large simulations on supercomputers. Since these simulations are expensive to run, I need to write the results every now and then to disk. Also, most supercomputers have maximum run-time of 1 or two days after which your job is automatically terminated. As a result I need to be able add a "resume" feature to my application.

For large datasets, I use "raw" binary files since this is the fastest you can dump information to disk. Later on, I can convert these binary files to formats that can be post-processed on a normal desktop. However, I also need to log some parametric information about the simulation when the code is running so that I wont have any problem figuring out what set of parameters do my result correspond to.

Furthermore, I need to have a configure file so that the parameters can be set from when I start/resume jobs. What I want to do is to merge logging/configure file into one step so that the code can log all needed information into a configure file for the next resume. I also need this file to be easily human-readable, hierarchical, and have good support in terms of libraries for parsing. My main concern is the language I'm developing in, namely `C++` but it could be nice to have support in `python` as well.

So far I'm doing this in `xml` using `boost::property_tree` but I'm not sure this is the best way to go. Specifically, my `xml` files seem a little bit too verbose! Are there any better options for the file format that I could use? How about library support? I prefer header-only libraries to prevent changes to the build structure.

Comment: If you want interoperability between languages and library availability, XML is the way to go. (Or maybe JSON but I have no idea what's available for C++ for that.) The verbosity sucks but I'd recommend just dealing with it. It's not like you're going to hand-edit the file anyway, and you don't mention any performance problems with parsing the file. (Which is easier to do efficiently with XML anyway.) If space is a problem, compression should help.

Comment: I had precisely the same problem a few years ago.  Your XML solution sounds better than anything I implemented.  I would recommend logging your parameters to a different file than you log your data but, otherwise, your approach sounds good.  (There is HDF, the Hierarchical Data Format, but this is not human-readable.)  A mistake I made was to lack good revision control on my code, with (a) the revision number dumped with the runtime parameters and (b) a concise changelog.  If your research extends longer than six months, you'll never remember which code produced which results without this.

Comment: If you can use a flat file, then by all means, use a flat file!  If you need hierarchical data, then either XML or JSON are worth considering.

Comment: Also consider that you can embed the raw datasets in the XML documents encoded as base-64. This should cut down on the verbosity as you don't need to map your data atoms to XML elements, but I'm not sure if there's a way to efficiently deserialise base64 into a struct. (Deserialising into a blob of bytes and casting maybe?)

Comment: This brings me to a question actually: what do you mean when you say the resulting XML is verbose? That is, what type of verbosity you'd ideally like to get rid of?

Comment: @millimoose Thanks for the input. The reason I like the hierarchical property of XML is mainly because my objects have a very hierarchical data structure. Its seems a little bit verbose tome since it kinda is ... I particularly find the idea of a single tag for everything ugly! (unless you use attributes which makes sense for some variables). To me JSON looks more polished!

Comment: @thb Right now I use `XDMF` for my "heavy" data files. Bindary files to store the actual data and `xmf` files that have all the lightweight information. I'm considering `HDF5` mainly due to its good ability for organizing data and parallel IO but I have not yet added that feature.

I use `SVN` for my version control have a not-so-bad changelog :) but your idea of including revision number logged by the code; that's definitely helpful.

Comment: @GradGuy If you can use JSON in C++ with a library you like (having looked at the docs for `property_tree`, it seems it supports JSON as well as XML so that should be a "yes"); and it gets rid of more or less the clutter you don't want to have in your output (i.e. extraneous elements); and you don't need streaming parsing/serialisation (which is useful for dealing with huge data sets, but less common in JSON toolkits than in XML), then go ahead and switch formats. The formats in and of themselves are both equally suitable for the use case "dump a data structure into a text file".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be in a very unique situation for a standard filetype that Python does *not* handle -- so as long as you stick with the standards (ie xml, json, ini, ...), the requirement to work well with python should never be a concern.

As others have said, JSON and XML are your best choices. You can never go wrong with industry standards. Better documentation, more widely tested, better readability of your code -- from what it sounds like, XML and JSON will both do what you want and encoding/decoding them are comparable. If filesize is a concern, I believe in uncompressed form, JSON is a bit more lightweight -- if it is not, just pick the file type that is more human-readable for you.